# Service always in background

Tags: android, service, background, timertask

I did create an Android app to send text messages every fifteen seconds. I did create a service that make it, and it never must end because I need to send alerts to my clients and is critical losing messages. 
The service code is the following:

```
public class AppService extends Service {
private static final long _updateIntervar = 15000;
private static final long _initialInterval = 100;
private static Timer timer = new Timer();
private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock = null;

public AppService() {}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = manager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, AppService.class.getName());
    this.runingAppService();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mWakeLock.release();
    stopForeground(true);
}

public void runingAppService() {
    try {
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sendMessages();
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(task, _initialInterval, _updateIntervar);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Common.showToast(e.getMessage(), Common._shortPeriodToast);
    }
}

private void sendMessages() {
    if (InternalData.getStatusLogin() && InternalData.getStatusService()) {
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
        data.put("OPTION", "GET_MESSAGES");
        data.put("DISTRIBUTOR", String.valueOf(InternalData.getIdDistribuidor()));
        data.put("SMS_GATEWAY", String.valueOf(InternalData.getIdGateWay()));
        HttpServerRequest.getDataMessages(data);
        HttpServerRequest.setMessageReceived(SMS.readInboxSMS());
        System.gc();
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    startForeground(Process.myPid(), new Notification());
    mWakeLock.acquire();
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Null");
    return null;
}}
```

I use a TimerTask on my service for call to method sendMessages () and it does, but after five or sometimes less my service is stopped. If anyone has any idea that I do wrong, I am going to thanks them so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to return START_STICKY from onStartCommand method:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    startForeground(Process.myPid(), new Notification());
    mWakeLock.acquire();
    return START_STICKY;
```

}

START_STICKY is used for services that are explicitly started and stopped as needed:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

Comment: Thanks for your response, I try with this method. Regards.